# Debugging fail! in library

Tags: debugging, exception, rust

I have been structuring my code such that I have a library that I am then using in another file. This has been working well except today when when I ran into an error thrown by the `fail!` macro (index out of bounds).
Specifically I have no idea where they are thrown from. The report says that they are being thrown when I load the library with `extern crate blah = "blabla"`, but this isn't true as when I comment out some function calls in my test file everything runs fine.

One Idea I had was to manually include all of the files and not use the library at all. This seemed very hacky... Gdb also didn't help (despite -g flag).

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the lack of clarity. This is a runtime issue. I have mocked up some sample code that reproduces this error.

Library file:

```
#![crate_id = "that"]
#![crate_type = "rlib"]

pub mod thing {
  fn a() {
    let v = vec!(1f32);
    println!("{}", v.get(3));
  }

  pub fn b() {
    a();
  }
}
```

Bin file:

```
extern crate that;

fn main() {
  that::thing::b();
}
```

When compiling and running, I get the following error:

```
task '<main>' failed at 'index out of bounds: the len is 1 but the index is 3', lib.rs:1
```

While this report is indeed correct, the line number / location is misleading. For this simple problem its easy to see whats wrong. This is not the case for a larger file.

**Edit 2**

Result of running with RUST_BACKTRACE=1:

```
>>>>>>> RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./bin 

task '<main>' failed at 'index out of bounds: the len is 1 but the index is 3', lib.rs:1
stack backtrace:
   1:           0x4661d0 - rt::backtrace::imp::write::hfe294d72359867edAZy::v0.11.0.pre
   2:           0x44d850 - rt::unwind::begin_unwind_inner::h0c8451a5a31731e8Hzy::v0.11.0.pre
   3:           0x44cd30 - rt::unwind::begin_unwind_fmt::h2e6bc3145b6b3fb9Ryy::v0.11.0.pre
   4:           0x4660e0 - rust_begin_unwind
   5:           0x4a75d0 - failure::begin_unwind::h3bb6514279e9a504IOv::v0.11.0.pre
   6:           0x4a7610 - failure::fail_bounds_check::he1ed5c80925626c6IMv::v0.11.0.pre
   7:           0x44c810 - vec::Vec<T>::get::h5370221266733407395::v0.0
   8:           0x44b0f0 - thing::a::h3f669f2dfb075f3cfaa::v0.0
   9:           0x44cd00 - thing::b::h8fc1d5bafb3ab544rba::v0.0
  10:           0x4032b0 - main::he270e826329bbcf4faa::v0.0
  11:           0x44af90 - start::closure.7862
  12:           0x4617c0 - rt::task::Task::run::closure.25316
  13:           0x46db00 - rust_try
  14:           0x461710 - rt::task::Task::run::hb455d17a166d559b4ow::v0.11.0.pre
  15:           0x44abd0 - start::h58e604f51e8fd72cipe::v0.11.0.pre
  16:           0x44ab40 - lang_start::h90f473af132f8958Coe::v0.11.0.pre
  17:           0x4032e0 - main
  18:     0x7ff54744df10 - __libc_start_main
  19:           0x4031b0 - <unknown>
  20:                0x0 - <unknown>
```

Comment: Is the failure in *compiling* your code or in *running* it? Please provide the full console output.

Comment: You may want to try running your program with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a complete stacktrace.

Comment: Just added sample file and console output. Sorry for the lack of specificity in my original post and the delay.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 the RUST_BACKTRACE=1 is a nice trick to know. It certainly does tell me the function that was in issue, but no line number and its a little cryptic. Edited with result.

Comment: @luke: frame 7 and 8 tell you what you need to know here, it's the `.get` call in function `a`; I guess the functions in your bigger example might be larger and so tracking down the exact cause is more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

To debug panics as they happen, set a breakpoint on `rust_panic` function.

```
b rust_panic
```